# How can I make a black UISegmentedControl show up with a visible selection highlight?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a simple segmented control in a toolbar.  It has a black tint.  When one of the segments is selected, there is no visual indicator to show this.  Now normally it would darken the selected segment, but you can't darken black.  When a normal button bar button is pressed, it turns a lighter gray to indicate that it is pressed.  How can I do the same for the segmented control?

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the tintColor

```
 NSString *firstStr = @"ABC";
NSString *secondStr = @"Catégories";
NSArray *arTemp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstStr, secondStr, nil];
UISegmentedControl *segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:arTemp];
[arTemp release];
arTemp = nil;
segment.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
segment.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for.  I need to only have the selected segment be gray, not all segments.

Comment: I know it's the inverse of what you want; selected is Black and unselected is darkGray. It's been a long time since I wrote that code and after some failed test I just went that way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you looked at ios5's new appearance proxy? That should be able to help you out.
2. If you need pre ios5 support as well,  what I've seen is that it's easy enough to make your own segmented control- something as simple as a set of buttons with custom background images (and that deselect the other buttons when one button is selected) or a more thorough approach as described in this post on [idevrecipes.com](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/11/custom-segmented-controls/)

   The site in the link above also has a good discussion on how to make button images for a segmented control with the caps cut off.
3. A third idea, is that you take a regular segmented control, set the tint to a shade of grey slightly lighter than black, then play with the touch events (touch up inside, touch up outside) to basically reverse the normal behavior of the segmented control, making the black button on the control behave like it's the selected one.  However I think this would be against apple's intentions (although this is what the new Reminders app in iOS5 does), and I haven't tried it to see if there's any subtle nuance that would make this not work.

I'd like to hear how you end up tackling this. Good luck!